# Create Passcode view in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard

I want to create view in android that reads 4 character pass-code. I want to focus prev element when user press backspace. Is it possible to capture backspace event when selected view is empty?

I Also want to close/hide keyboard after last character is entered. Is it possible?

Comment: post some of your code and lets see where its going wrong !

Comment: Hi Panther i have updated question with the code. even when calling clearFocus(); soft keyboard is not closed and regarding backspace can you let me know how can we capture it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overwritten onKey & onFocusChange functions and used ZeroWidthString("\u200B") to capture Delete Event from Soft Keyboard. Following is the code sniff

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
            if (tv.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ZeroWidthString))
                moveToPrevField();
            else
                tv.setText(ZeroWidthString);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) v;
    if (hasFocus) {
        tv.setText(ZeroWidthString);
    }
    else if (tv.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ZeroWidthString)) {
        tv.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture the `backspace`,its actually the delete key in android. you can capture it via

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
             //delete key pressed
             }
    return false;       
        }
});
```

To hide the keyboard try this

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```